# Error Accessing Amazon EC2 info using boto3 in python3 and example code

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I followed the [boto3 quickstart guide](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html) to connect to my AWS instance after running the `aws configure` command and installing the `awscli` library from `pip`. But when I try to connect, I get the following error:

```
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 404 No such domain

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 271, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.ca-central-1a.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 404 No such domain',)))
```

I am thinking it has something to do with the region location info that is erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue was a gotcha with the region tag. Even though AWS lists the region names as `ca-central-1a` and `ca-central-1b` respectively, boto3 is looking for only `ca-central-1` as the location, otherwise the aforementioned error in the question will appear.

edited, thanks to @MarkB's comment below ca-central-1a and -1b are availability zones in the region ca-central-1. Lesson learned.

Comment: `ca-central-1a` and `ca-central-1b` are not region names, they are names of availability zones within the region `ca-central-1`.

Comment: @MarkB ah, that makes a lot more sense now. thanks! If you want to write an answer, I will accept yours as the correct one, or I will edit mine, up to you.